# How to increment my Var2 after Var1 reaches some value on Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I need to Increment my Var2 after Var1 reaches some value, how to do that in Jmeter.

I tried with JSR223 with JavaScript but no luck (I am new to JS).

Ex:

```
Var1 = FirstName
Var2 = LastName
```

My Usecase:

```
FirstName1.LastName1
FirstName1.LastName2
FirstName1.LastName3
FirstName1.LastName4
FirstName1.LastName5

FirstName2.LastName1
FirstName2.LastName2
FirstName2.LastName3
FirstName2.LastName4
FirstName2.LastName5
.
.
.
```

I tried the JS as below and and after that I am calling the FirstName from JS like `${__javaScript(‘${FirstName}’)}`.

```
FirstName = 1;
function k()
{
   if (${LastName} == 5)
   {
      FirstName++;
      return FirstName;
   }
   else
   {
      return FirstName;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend switching to [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language, in case when you need to do this calculation multiple times with multiple threads Groovy will work much faster than JavaScript.

Example Groovy code would look like:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

int FirstName = 1;  
String lastName = vars.get("LastName");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(lastName);
if (m.find()) {
    int LastName = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));    
    if (LastName >= 5) {
        FirstName++;
    }   
}

return "FirstName" + FirstName;
```

See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more detailed explanation, benchmarks and scripting best practices.